# How remove from two maps the identical keys

Tags: java, api, dictionary, java-8, interface

I created two maps in Java that contain the same type of Keys and Values:

```
Map<Position,Movement> A;
Map<Position,Movement> B;
```

I want to remove from them both (not create a new Map) the keys that are the same. I don't care if the value is different or not. For example, if `A` has Position: `a2`, Movement: `n,n` and `B` has Position: `a2`, Movement: `1,2` those entries should be removed.

I wonder if there is a fast way to do that without iterating the shortest map and compare every single key.

Thanks

Comment: `A.keySet().removeAll(B.keySet())` removes all keys in `B` from `A`

Comment: yeah, but I want to delete the keys from B as well.

Comment: Just do the statement also in reverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `Iterator` on the `keySet()` of one of the maps and remove the element from the iterator and the other map if the key is present in the other map.

```
Iterator<String> itr = map1.keySet().iterator();
String key;
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    key = itr.next();
    if (map2.containsKey(key)) {
        itr.remove();
        map2.remove(key);
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map1.put("a", "1");
        map1.put("b", "1");
        map1.put("x", "1");
        map1.put("c", "1");
        map1.put("z", "1");
        map1.put("d", "1");

        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map2.put("w", "1");
        map2.put("x", "1");
        map2.put("b", "1");
        map2.put("y", "1");
        map2.put("c", "1");
        map2.put("z", "1");

        Iterator<String> itr = map1.keySet().iterator();
        String key;
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            key = itr.next();
            if (map2.containsKey(key)) {
                itr.remove();
                map2.remove(key);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(map1);
        System.out.println(map2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{a=1, d=1}
{w=1, y=1}
```

## [Update]

Solution using `Stream`:

```
map1.keySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(k -> map2.containsKey(k))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .forEach(k -> {
        map1.remove(k);
        map2.remove(k);
    });
```

## [Another Update]

Given below is a compact version (Thanks to [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)) of the first solution:

```
for (Iterator<String> itr = map1.keySet().iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
    if (map2.keySet().remove(itr.next())) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah that's how I programmed but I was looking for something more related to the API and using lambda expressions. Thanks!

Comment: You can replace `map2.containsKey(key)` directly with `map2.remove(key) != null` and then drop the second line in the if statement. This works of course only when the map doesn't allow null values

Comment: @LauraGalera - I've posted a working solution using `Stream` as an update. I hope, it fulfils your requirement.

Comment: @Lino or `map2.keySet().remove(key)` which directly returns a `boolean` and solves the problem with `null` values. It enables more concise surrounding code as well: `for(Iterator<String> itr = map1.keySet().iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) if(map2.keySet().remove(itr.next()) itr.remove();`

Comment: @Holger even better, great addition

Comment: @Holger - Thanks for the valuable suggestion. I've added it as an update at the end of my answer as it may be difficult to understand it from the comment due to formatting limitations of comment.